# comprimir una carpeta y su contenido a tar.gz en visual basic .net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

como puedo comprimir una carpeta y sus contenido en formato tar.gz desde visual basic, he buscado y obtuve este ejemplo:

```
Dim archivoTarPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(archivoSalidaPath), "masivos.tar")
        Using archivoTarStream As New FileStream(archivoTarPath, FileMode.Create)
            Using archivoTar As New TarArchive(archivoTarStream, TarMode.Create)
                Dim p = archivoTar.CreateEntries(directorioPath, "")
            End Using
        End Using

        ' Convertir el archivo tar en formato gzip
        Dim archivoGzipPath = Path.Combine("../datos/gzip/masivos", "masivo_" & idMasivo.ToString() & ".tar.gz")
        Using archivoGzipStream As New FileStream(archivoGzipPath, FileMode.Create)
            Using gzipStream As New GZipStream(archivoGzipStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal)
                Using archivoTarStream As New FileStream(archivoTarPath, FileMode.Open)
                    archivoTarStream.CopyTo(gzipStream)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

pero no se que libreria debo importar exactamente, intente con la SharpZipLib que ya no esta disponible para visual estudio igualmente con aspose, pero no logro mi objetivo espero me ayuden.

Comment: En que versión de .net estas trabajando?

Comment: estoy en la version visual studio 2019 comunity con basic, leyendo un poco mas me indica que deben tener la misma version del system.buffer y segun entiendo la version 2019 trabaja con 4.5.1 pero la libreria que uso solo soporta hasta 4.0.2, hay alguna manera de cambiarla